# Override members on a built-in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, client-side

I would like to override the default behavior of the offsetParent member of all html elements. I would like to do something like this if it's possible:

```
// For <div id="foo"></div>
var oFooElem = document.getElementById("foo");
oFooElem._offsetParent = oFooElem.offsetParent;
oFooElem.prototype.offsetParent = function() {
    window.status = 'offsetParent called.';
    return this._offsetParent;
};
```

Is this even possible? If so, please post the corrected code sample. Thanks!

**Update:**

@some Thank you for your help. It sounds like this is not possible. I have expanded on the problem that provoked this question in a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371468/looking-for-an-elegant-workaround-for-ie-67-unspecified-error-bug-when-accessin) if you're interested.

Comment: I get Exception "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object" when I try in firefox.

Comment: You can't do this on the offsetParent property AFAIK.  What are you hoping to accomplish? e.g. are you trying to get a true top/left coordinate all the way up the hierarchy?

Comment: I'm hoping to cleanly fix this problem. http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/11/29/ie-6-7-unspecified-error-when-accessing-offsetparent-javascript.aspx

Comment: @CodeChef: I updated my answer and also posted a reply on that other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible.
In firefox I get exception "setting a property that only has a getter", IE gives error, Chrome gives error, but in Opera it works (if I assign it on the element, not the prototype)!

But you have another problem. offsetParent isn't a function so it will never be called like a function and your alert will never happen. In opera (the only browser I found where you could replace it in) you only get the function back.

You can however add a new function (will work in Firefox, Chrome and Opera but not in IE since IE don't have the constructor property):

```
var e = document.getElementById("mydiv"); //Get a div element
//Adds a _offsetParent function to all DIV elements.
e.constructor.prototype._offsetParent=function(){
  alert("offset parent called"); return this.offsetParent;
};
e._offsetParent();
```

**Update**
By reading your description [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/11/29/ie-6-7-unspecified-error-when-accessing-offsetparent-javascript.aspx) I see your error:

1. you get a reference to the object
   called myInnerContent
2. you remove that object from the DOM when you replace the content of the outer tag.
3. you try to get the parent from the old object who is orphan and 
   that no longer are in the DOM. IE gives you an Error and Firefox gives you null.

You already have the solution on your page: Save the name of the object. Optionally you can choose to update the global variable when you update the content, or only update the innerHTML of the inner div.