# Unspecified Error from Google Maps API on IE8

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

My page is returning SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error in IE8.  I think I have found the reason for it but no solution.

The error is coming from Google Maps API, function mq(a,b).  The problem is that IE8 does not appear to be able to handle getBoundingClientRect() on asynchronously loaded content, and I'm loading content using jQuery.load().  The error doesn't occur if I create a page with the same content loading with the page rather than asynchronously.

The error occurs on page load and then any time the window is resized, no matter whether a map is displayed or not.

I discovered that people were having the same problem with jQuery a few years ago:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4996
[Is there a workaround for IE 6/7 "Unspecified Error" bug when accessing offsetParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371468/looking-for-a-workaround-for-ie-6-7-unspecified-error-bug-when-accessing-offse)

Does anybody know of a fix or workaround?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: There is no function called `getBoundingClientRect()` in the Maps API. You're going to need to provide some more information, like an actual test page.

Comment: Can post a link to a page which demonstrates the issue?

@MichaelGeary `getBoundingClientRect` is a DOM method and it is highly likely that the maps api code uses this method internally.

Comment: I have posted a test page here:https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Y3wXhWdoQebnBUV2RNRWhJZE0/test-shell.html. I'm getting an error in both IE8 and IE9. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My colleague confirmed the error occurs also in IE10

Comment: It appears that to reproduce the error I have to instatiate Google Maps and then load another page. The test page does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I am posting my answer in case someone else has the same problem.

To reproduce the error, I had to first load a page with a Places Autocomplete input.  Then, I would load other content, replacing the field.  The error was happening when the window resize event could not find the dimensions of the nonexistent input.

I solved the problem by calling

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(window, 'resize');
```

before loading the new content.

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me. After a dozen of ideas, I ended up with the following working(!) solution:

Before loading the content, destroy the object that the map is attached to.

e.g. if your map is set using:

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);`

use this code before doing the ajax request:

`$('#map-canvas').remove();`