# In Google Maps getBoundingClientRect gives Unspecified Error in IE

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8, google-maps-markers

Relating to question in:
[Unspecified Error from Google Maps API on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842886/unspecified-error-from-google-maps-api-on-ie8)

In function
    function Mp(a,b){ .. }
the following line of code triggers an error 
    var e=a.getBoundingClientRect();

1. To replicate this error

   1. Make a Google Map page (make sure it is tall enough that you've spare space to scroll the page, don't make the map full-screen)
   2. Place a Marker
   3. Open the app in IE ( I tested in 10) in debug mode
   4. When page loads, click on a marker such that it shows the info-window i.e. the pop-over
   5. Try scrolling the page

      > You'll get the error.

getBoundingClientRect(), an IE feature which returns positions of containers. The issues  may be related to tool-tips i.e. info-windows.

Look more at : http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/

Tried the solution: google.maps.event.clearListeners(window, 'resize');
It din't work.

> Sample App: https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Y3wXhWdoQebnBUV2RNRWhJZE0/test-shell.html
>   Courtesy: @user2250544

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or workaround for this issue?? I also experience the same problem and get figure out how to fix it ?!

Comment: @Jeroen1984: have a look at my added answer. This bug drove me crazy, but I found a working solution (at least for me ;)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a filthy hack that seems to work, if you're into that kinda thing:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = (function () { 
    var oldGetBoundingClientRect = HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect; 
    return function() { 
        try { 
            return oldGetBoundingClientRect.apply(this, arguments); 
        } catch (e) { 
            return { 
                left: '', 
                right: '', 
                top: '', 
                bottom: '' 
            }; 
        } 
    }; 
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix the error by Despose GMap before postback:

```
unction fnGMap_initialize(strFrame) {
var divDealerMap = document.getElementById("divDealerMap");

var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 0), 
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

        oGMap = new google.maps.Map(divDealerMap, mapOptions);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(oGMap_Dispose);
}


function oGMap_Dispose() {
    var divDealerMap = document.getElementById("divDealerMap");   
    if (divDealerMap) divDealerMap.parentNode.removeChild(divDealerMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the browser cache as mentioned here: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/21849?hl=en helped me to fix similar issues