# Google Maps in IE11 gives "Unspecified error"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting a very strange error when using custom Google Maps in a website of one of our clients. The map has some markers on it, and when you open the marker you can see a dialog with the address of that location. When I close this dialog (obviously by clicking the cross) in IE11, I get an "Unspecified error". For some reason, this error is being thrown from the method "getBoundingClientRect()". No other browser has this issue (not even IE8).

I am using Google Maps API version 3.14.

Does anyone know what this could be? I'm not sure if it's necessary to place any code, but I'm willing to do that if that makes everything more clear.

Comment: Can't help you without code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Yes. Try to create a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue.

Comment: A jsfiddle is useful, but the (preferably minimal) code that is exhibiting the problem should be posted in the question.

Comment: Similar to -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275088/in-google-maps-getboundingclientrect-gives-unspecified-error-in-ie ..clear the browser cache

Comment: check the console in the F12 tools. The exception should be logged there. You can click the link and go to the offending code and set a breakpoint to debug the problem. My guess is it is Google playing games, probably browser sniffing instead of feature detection.

Comment: Hello, I've been looking in the code, and this is where the marker is put together and returned: [link](http://winterwerp.nl/media/ie11code.png). The marker is then added to an array and added to the map. This is the error I'm getting: [link](http://winterwerp.nl/media/ie11error.png). It looks like it's being thrown in an external Google-library. Thanks for your answers btw. I've spoken to my collegue about posting the code to JSFiddle, but we don't know if that's the best idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this fix for IE (place this code on top):

```
HTMLElement.prototype._getBoundingClientRect=HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect; 
HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = function() {
    try {
        return this._getBoundingClientRect();
    } catch(e) {
        return { top : this.offsetTop, left : this.offsetLeft };
    }
}
```